# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemName')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
this.InvoiceForm=this.fb.group({
          InvoiceNumber:[''],
          EntryDate:[''],
          InvoiceItem:this.fb.array([this.AddItemFormGroup()])
      
        })

AddItemFormGroup()
{
  return this.fb.group({
    ItemName:[''],
    ItemType:['']
  })



 Save()
    {
      console.log(this.InvoiceForm.value);
    
console.log(this.InvoiceForm.InvoiceItem[0].ItemName);
    }
```

when I log the values it shows but when I log the value of specific row of nested form array it give error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemName')

Comment: `this.InvoiceForm.controls.InvoiceItem.controls[0].controls.ItemName` if you need control or `this.InvoiceForm.value.InvoiceItem[0].ItemName` if you need value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log((this.InvoiceForm.get('InvoiceItem') as FormArray).at(0).get('ItemName').value)`

since `InvoiceForm` is a `FormGroup` object, you cannot directly access the controls by indexing the key. You either have to do it as @Eugene mentioned in the comment using: `this.InvoiceForm.controls.InvoiceItem` or by using `get` like this: `this.InvoiceForm.get('InvoiceItem')` which will return the `InvoiceItem` control.

Now if you wanted to access the value of the control you'd have to do this `this.InvoiceForm.get('InvoiceItem').value`, but since `InvoiceItem` in our case is not a simple `FormControl` but a `FormArray` we can only use the properties available to `FormArray`

And since its a `FormArray` we can use the `.at(index)` method to get the specific control or value. We use `as FormArray` since `typescript` assumes the type is a generic `FormControl` and not a `FormArray`